# How to make a QByteArray from a Database file

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, arrays, qt5

Using [QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) from QT5, I was able to make a bytes array from a txt file or an image, used decode after and recreated the file correctly. But, when I tried with a .db file (SQLITE) it didn't work.

I noticed that when you open a .db with a text editor, you will see "SQLite format 3" followed by encoded characters. After making a QByteArray from a .db file, followed by decode() to recreate the file, when I opened it with a text editor, the file only contains the text "SQLite format 3".

Does QByteArray only work with txt file or Image file?

If it does, how can I make a Array of bytes from a .db (SQLITE) file.

Thanks

---

Update1 (The code belows works):

```
QFile file("C:/database.db");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    qDebug()<<"You are stupid!";

QByteArray byteArray = file.readAll();

QFile file2("C:/database2.db");
file2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file2.write(byteArray);

file2.close();
file.close();
```

---

Update2:

About the decode I mentioned in my initial question, I was using the following:

```
QString QFile::decodeName(const QByteArray & localFileName)
```

which make no sense when you read carefully the documentation and was just wrong. :)

Comment: What do you mean by `decode()`? Please show a minimal self-contained example. This is supposed to be easy, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: No, `QByteArray` doesn't care about what's inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not open that file with QIODevice::Text flag.

Check this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum